# Subscribed report doesn't display images

Tags: reporting, formula

I've got a report with a custom field (Task Due Status) that displays a red/yellow/green flag based on Due Date.  Report display perfectly when viewed in Salesforce.

When I 'Subscribe' to the report, here's the result I get in my email.

[image]

How do I get the actual image to display rather than the URL to it?  Here's my custom field's formula:

[image]

Comment: What you are hoping for likely cannot be accomplished without staggering dev effort.

Comment: @AdrianLarson do you mean creating a repot in VF or lightning that displays images?

Comment: Yes, you are going to have to roll your own data retrieval mechanism (custom Apex controller), UI element (Visualforce), scheduled job, subscription mechanism, and email sending mechanism.

Comment: Aha got it...too tedious